# Flutter ListView doesn't refresh UI with setState(), although itemCount and attached list update correctly

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, reactive-programming

I see a lot of people with very similar problems, but nothing I try works.

### **CONTEXT**

I have a list of favorited ideas. Whenever I click in a button inside the ideaItem, it should get removed from the list.

### **PROBLEM**

When I delete any ideaItem, the last one from the screen gets always removed, instead of the one I clicked on. My FavoriteIdeasListView seems to update correctly the items count, this means that the attached List works, but the UI is not redrawing the ideaItems.

### **WHAT I HAVE TRIED**

- At the beginning I had the delete functionality directly on ideaItem, I read I should do a VoidCallback and handle deletion from the List itself, so it would notice the change. It didn't work
- I also tried with a Stream Builder, so the stream would notify the ListView to refresh. Also it didn't work
- I try calling SetState all the time and it's not reloading, it only builds the list at the beginning on the initialState.

```
    class FavoritesList extends StatefulWidget {
      FavoritesList({Key key}) : super(key: key);

      @override
      _FavoritesListState createState() => _FavoritesListState();
    }

    class _FavoritesListState extends State<FavoritesList> {

      List<Idea> _favorites = [];

      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        favoritesInitialState();
      }

      Future <void> favoritesInitialState() async {
        List<Idea> ideas = await IdeasDB.db.ideas();
        setState(() {
          _favorites = ideas;
        });
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('Favorites')),
            body: Center(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _favorites.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final idea = _favorites[index];
                  return IdeaItem(
                    idea: idea,
                    onFavoriteToggle: () => deleteFromFavorites(idea),
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
        );
      }

      void deleteFromFavorites(Idea idea) async {
        await IdeasDB.db.deleteIdea(idea.url);
        List<Idea> newIdeas = await IdeasDB.db.ideas();
        setState(() {
          this._favorites = newIdeas;
        });
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can see only two possible options for why this happens.

First one is obvious, your `IdeasDB.db.deleteIdea(idea.url);` doesn't delete correct idea from DB;

The second one is less obvious, it's because your Element Tree couldn't recognize what's a widget you are trying to delete. It happens only with Stateful Widgets as your `IdeaItem` could be.

Solution then is to use `key` attribute for your `IdeaItem` widget
like this:

```
ListView.builder(
  itemCount: _favorites.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    final idea = _favorites[index];
    return IdeaItem(
      key: ValueKey(idea.url) // or UniqueKey()
      idea: idea,
      onFavoriteToggle: () => deleteFromFavorites(idea),
    );
  },
),
```

and in your `IdeaItem` widget you have to pass that key to your parent `Stateful widget` like in this example:

```
class IdeaItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final Idea idea;
  Function onFavoriteToggle;

  IdeaItem({Key key, this.idea, this.onFavoriteToggle}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _IdeaItemState createState() => _IdeaItemState();
}
```

Comment: It works! the solution was to add the key because indeed my IdeaItem was also Stateful! Amazing!

Answer (score 3):

Try to change

```
onFavoriteToggle: () => deleteFromFavorites(index),
```

and then

```
  void deleteFromFavorites( int index) async {
    await IdeasDB.db.deleteIdea(idea.url);
    setState(() {
      this._favorites.removeAt(index);
    });
  }
```

See if it works. If yes, there is probably error on `deleteIdea()`.

Also, you know which item should be deleted, so you don't need to await to reload the List from your db. `await IdeasDB.db.ideas();`

If you want to be sure you can wrap your code with Try catch

```
  void deleteFromFavorites(int index) async {
    try {
      await IdeasDB.db.deleteIdea(idea.url);
      setState(() {
        this._favorites.removeAt(index);
      });
    } catch (_) {
      print('ERROR');
    }
  }
```

Comment: The solution was to pass the 'key' parameter. I upvote because the optimise solution removing unnecessary waiting! Thanks!